# Geas spell effect

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

From page 244, PHB - description of the **5th** level spell *Geas*:

> You place a magical command on a creature that you can see within range, forcing it to carry out some service or refrain from some action or course of activity as you decide. (...) While the creature is charmed by you, it takes 5d10 psychic damage each time it acts in a manner directly counter to your instructions, **but no more than once each day**.

So my question is what will happen if some monster casts *Geas* on a player and succeeded, forcing him not to attack for example. As I understand the description although player failed his saving throw he CAN disobey the command but he will take 5d10 dmg. And if he survives it he can now disobey it as if the spell was not there? He can take dmg only once a day.

From page 278, PHB - description of the **2th** level spell *Suggestion*:

> (...) The target must make a Wisdom saving throw. **On a failed save, it pursues the course of action you described to the best of its ability.**

The wording of *Suggestion* spell does not give any way for charmed creature to disobay.

And if I understand it correctly how to describe to the player under the spell the difference between those two spells? If a creature casts *Geas* how to tell the player that although he's charmed he can disobey but with consequences? :)

Comment: VTC-ing as primarily opinion based - There's nothing to make one way of explaining to the player better than any other way.

Comment: I'm unclear on what obstacle you're needing help to overcome here.

Comment: My doubts are about *Geas* spell effect, can charmed player disobey the command and if so what happens after taking dmg? Can he now disobey it freely? The second part of the question (answered by Bacon Bits) was about phrasing. Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: Please ask two different questions in two different questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, you're looking for phrasing here?  Honestly, it's not that hard to convey.

For *charm*:

> DM: He casts a spell on you, and tells you to stop attacking him.  Roll your saving throw.
>   P1: I fail.
>   DM: As the magic takes hold, you think not attacking this very friendly Wizard is an immensely good idea.  You're not sure how the idea even got in your head.  His eyes are glowing with such a jolly shade of red, after all.

For *suggestion*:

> DM: He casts a spell on you, and tells you to stop attacking him.  Roll your saving throw.
>   P1: I fail.
>   DM: As the magic takes hold, you look down and notice you're not holding your sword anymore.  It appears to be back in it's scabbard.  You realize he's right; there are much more important things to do than attack the Wizard.

For *geas*:

> DM: He casts a spell on you, and tells you to stop attacking him.  Roll your saving throw.
>   P1: I fail.
>   DM: As the magic takes hold, you get the distinct impression that the Wizard wasn't bluffing about not attacking him.  Not only do you find yourself unable to attack the target, but something tells you that doing so accidentally would have... *deadly* consequences.

Quite honestly, "don't attack me" is a pretty crap *geas*.  The spell should be used for something with a bit more teeth than that.  "Guard and protect me from attack," for example.

And, of course, for *dominate person*:

> DM: He casts a spell on you, and tells you to stop attacking him.  Roll your saving throw.
>   P1: I fail.
>   DM: Gimme your character sheet.  You can go have a smoke if you want.